# Printing a book

Tags: book-design, printing

I would create a document using latex, if I want to print the document and make a book out of it, how should I do it?

My document has 50 pages, and following requirements :

1. Double side printing
2. Book starts from right
3. Staples will be at the center of the sheet.

> First sheet will have pages 1, 2 and 49, 50
>
> Second sheet will have pages 3, 4 and 47, 48
>
> etc

How do I go about arranging this type of format?

Comment: If this is for printing a small number of copies, many PC printers now have an option to do this (sometimes called "Booklet Printing" on Canon printers)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Kirk, suppose you have a tex document named *mydoc.tex* (this contains your book, whith *twoside* in the class), then create a second document named *mydoc2up.tex* like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{mydoc.pdf}
\end{document}
```

compile this and enjoy!

Comment: +1 but is it necessary/beneficial to use `scrartcl`?

Comment: This worked much better than fiddling with the `booklet` package, thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure this works for windows, but on my linux-pc there is a programm called pdfbook, which does exactly, what you need. The manpage says:

"pdfbook is part of the "PDFjam" package of tools, whose homepage is at http://www.warwick.ac.uk/go/pdfjam."

Some years ago I used it and it worked well.

Comment: In fact, `pdfjam` is internally built on the `pdfpages` package  as well (it generates a temporary LaTeX document similar to the one suggested by hsigrist in his answer an then invokes `pdflatex` on it.) However, using `pdfbook` directly is more convenient (+1).

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use [booklet](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/booklet/booklet.pdf). If you use pdfpages you have to compile twice and know the location of the first file. If you already have a pdf that you do not want to edit anymore, you can use any command line tool like the aforementioned pdfbook which is much easier than running LaTeX again.

Comment: Could you add a sample document (perhaps with `lipsum` or `blindtext`) and its output?