# Print a document with exam class so that it can be folded into a book

Tags: paper-size, book-design, printing, exam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing a book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26669/printing-a-book)

Is there a method when printing on a5paper with `exam` class  so that it comes out like a book?

Folding down the middle, and have it print the pages in correct order, after you fold it, it follows the pages expected in a book.

Comment: @doncherry I have no idea what is wrote in that link. I don't understand.  Isn't there a command I can type that will do this in the area before \begin{document}

Comment: The easiest way seems to be in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26701/4012, where you first produce your document (with the `exam` class) as normal (you probably have to change your paper size to a6paper), and then create another document that puts the pages in the right order etc. -- this is the document whose source is provided in the answer. Another option seems to be the `booklet` package (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28779/4012); I haven't checked out how that works.

Comment: Just to make sure the concept of duplicates is clear: Your question is very similar to the one I linked to. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you. Also, show what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: @doncherry you know best.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's ironic or not .. did that other question help you with your problem?

Comment: @doncherry Yes you helped.  I hope I am not ironic, My english is not good.

Comment: My printer natively supports two-sided booklet printing. This has the advantage that I do not need to make any adjustments to the TeX file. Maybe you can find a similar printer.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen you have a name.