# can LaTeX help with book binding?

Tags: margins

Recently, a colleague of mine has done his own book binding. He has used LibreOffice. I am wondering if LaTeX could be used and if it could provide more assistance than LibreOffice.

The problem that I see, if I understand the binding process correctly, is that with 8 folios per stack, the outermost folio in the first stack contains pages number 1, 32 on one side and 2, 31 on the other side, etc.

Now, I am wondering, if LaTeX (or any of available modules) can help with this task? Basically, can LaTeX help with ordering the pages on the folios so that printing them is easy as pie?

**UPDATE**

This question is not exactly the same as [Printing a book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26669/printing-a-book) question. The other question wants to staple all of the folios of the document together at once. I want to be able to build sections from 8 folios (32 pages) and bind them together by sewing.

Comment: you might take a look at this edition of [peter wilson;s "glisterings" column](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99glister.pdf) in tugboat, which describes the arrangement of up to 16 pages on one sheet for creation of miniature books.

Comment: You can use the `pdfpages` package for that. It can use a `nup` key.

Comment: @Bernard Not to mention the `signature` key which is crucial here. The `nup` key will just put, say, 4 pages per sheet or whatever. The `signature` key permits automated ordering of the kind the OP wants.

Comment: @cfr: Oh! I thought the signature was only for the case of 4 pages per sheet. I see I misunderstood. I must say I never used `nup`, only the signature  (trying to make a personal edition of Edward Lear's ‘The story of the Four Little Children Who Went Round the World’ as beautiful as I could…).

Comment: @Bernard You may be right. I've never tried with more than that.

Comment: @cfr: I think `signature` is the key to this. Could you make it an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @ wilx I don't think so. I think @Bernard is right and the option only works for 2-up layouts (i.e. 4 logical pages per sheet - 2 per side). I didn't realise this just because I've only ever tried to use it for a layout of that kind. But I checked the documentation and it definitely states the limitation Bernard noted.

Comment: @cfr: Oh, I see.

Comment: @wilx Yes. It is a shame :(.

Comment: @MaartenDhondt: It is similar but not the same.

Comment: *sigh* This is not a duplicate.

Comment: There was a presentation by Martin Schroeder back in 2001 on a commercial imposition system which uses pdftex: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-3/tb72schroder.pdf

Comment: You could also post-process using a script driving `pdftk` (true for any PDF)

Comment: @ChrisH: Sure. But the less work I have to do myself the better. :)

Comment: @wilx, absolutely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see at least two different ways for two different ways to bind a book. The first way is to use `pdfpages`. I used that for "normal" binding with signatures. The other way is to use the `geometry`-package. This is good for press binding. Here are the specific examples:

### Signatures with `pdfpages`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,signature=4,landscape]{file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Explanations:

- `pages=-`: use the whole document
- `signature=x`: how many pages on one signature (should be a multiple of 4)
- `landscape`: print the pdf pages in landscape mode

The result is a pdf file with nice printed signatures. you can then print them in duplex mode and start the binding process.

more information here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages

### The `geometry`-way

(this is also good as a draft for books, see the `showcrop` option).

I think this is just good for a press binding with glue (personly I don't like that...)

`geometry` offers an option which sets some space on the left side

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-100] % expand if necessary
\end{document}
```

With the `geometry`-package you can also add the `showframe` option. This shows you the margins of the layout.

more information here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry

### Conclusion

For a good book with real binding you should use the `pdfpages` way. Not so good is that you need to create a pdf first. For now I didn't find a way to do something similar with `geometry`. That would be the best because you can directly create the final pdf. Good luck.

Comment: I have just tested it. Your first solution with `pdfpages` seems to be what I am looking for. I have tested with `signature=16`.

Comment: I think you understood the bookbinding process correctly. For beginners I recommend the very easy _coptic stitch_. It is also easy to learn. Sadly I didn't find a forum/community that I can recommend... But I think you will get it.

Comment: You can ask about book binding at [GraphicDesign.SE], it is on-topic there, under the tags [typography](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) and [print-design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/print-design).

Comment: @yo' Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks very much.